# First vote of a serial voting situation

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting

Recently a serial voter voted all of my questions, and the votes were reversed before 24 hours. That's where I came across [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).

> *Serial voting could happen for a variety of reasons, such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all of their posts to upvote them, or a user getting into an argument with another user and downvoting their posts indiscriminately in revenge.*

Now in a such case all the votes from that user will be reversed, but actually the very first vote is more likely to be a true vote in both cases, either upvotes or downvotes.

So I suggest that the very first vote of that situation should be left without reversing.

Comment: What do you propose if that user comes back and serial votes you once a week? That the first vote each time sticks, or should the system remember when one user serial votes for the other? If the former, then that defeats the purpose of reversing the votes as persistent enough serial voting can eventually cause the harm that un-reversed votes would cause. (Even if the account is suspended, theoretically they can rebuild and resume after a time.) If the later, how long should this be remembered? A month? A year? If neither, what do you suggest?

Comment: I don't think that the reward is worth the extra work to implement it.  In fact, I'm not convinced that there is any reward.

Comment: you said it : *more likely to be true*. so we can never know if it's true or not

Comment: It seems to me that leaving any of the votes in a serial voting situation would only encourage the serial voter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In reality, few of these serial voting cases have any real merit to them. In my experience, the vast majority of serial upvote cases that are reversed are from sock puppets or coordinated voting rings. Serial downvotes are almost always in retaliation for something.

Neither of these cases have anything to do with the actual value of the posts involved, so none of the votes are worth preserving in those cases. People already complain on a regular basis when the serial downvoting mechanism misses a vote or two due to its conservative thresholds. Letting a vote or two survive from sock puppets or voting rings would lead to vote inflation on bad posts.

Setting aside the work required to do this, I think its implementation would lead to more problems than it solves.